# HQL inner join query exlude objects in ManyToOne set member

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a Translations class e.g.:

```
 class Translation{
      String key;
      String type;
      String userId;
      @OneToMany
      Set<TranslationValue> translations;
 }
```

which holds a OneToMany relationship with a TranslationValue class e.g.:

```
 class TranslationValue{
      String language;
      String value;
      @ManyToOne
      Translation translation;
 }
```

I would like to query based on the TranslationValue.language member and return a list of Translation objects which contain a set with only 1 TranslationValue object -> the one which was used as query parameter e.g:

```
translationDao.findAllForLanguage("en");
```

This would return every translation object in the db that has TranslationValue.language = "en" and furthermore would remove from each object Translation.translations where language is not "en".

So far I'm returning a list of all Translation objects which have a TranslationValue object with a language="en" member in their respective translations Sets. I need to remove all TranslationValue objects that don't have language="en" though.

EDIT: progress

This query returns the correct amount of hits, but all values are null. ->

```
 @Override
public List<Translation> findAllForLanguage2(String language) {
    //TODO:finish
    final Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "select new " + getDomain().getSimpleName() + "(t.key,t.clientName,t.userId,t.type,t.platform,tv) from " + getDomain().getSimpleName() + " t right join t.translations tv where tv = some(from tv where tv.language = :language)");
    query.setParameter("language", language);


    return query.getResultList();
}

printing all from query
translation: Translation{key='null', clientName='null', userId='null', type=null, platform='null', translations=null}
translation: Translation{key='null', clientName='null', userId='null', type=null, platform='null', translations=null}
translation: Translation{key='null', clientName='null', userId='null', type=null, platform='null', translations=null}
translation: Translation{key='null', clientName='null', userId='null', type=null, platform='null', translations=null}
translation: Translation{key='null', clientName='null', userId='null', type=null, platform='null', translations=null}
translation: Translation{key='null', clientName='null', userId='null', type=null, platform='null', translations=null}
```

This query returns a Object [], where the second object is actually the TranslationValue object I want, but the Translation object is null ->

```
    @Override
public List<Object> findAllForLanguage(String language) {
    //TODO:finish
    final Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "from " + getDomain().getSimpleName() + " t full join t.translations tv where tv = some(from tv where tv.language = :language))");
    query.setParameter("language", language);


    return query.getResultList();
}

printing all from query
null
TranslationValue{language='en', value='feed'}
null
TranslationValue{language='en', value='feed'}
null
TranslationValue{language='en', value='broken'}
null
TranslationValue{language='en', value='broken'}
null
TranslationValue{language='en', value='water'}
null
TranslationValue{language='en', value='broken'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should do fine

```
select t from Translation t join t.translations tv 
where tv.language = :language 
and size(t.translations) = 1
```

Comment: Would this return only the Translation object who's translations Set has a size of 1? Because that's not what I need. I want to use my input variable to reduce the number of objects in the set.

Comment: So, you want to delete rows from the database? A select query won't do that. And the Set of translation values loaded by Hibernate will always contain all the translation values of the translation.

Comment: I don't want to delete rows from the db. The translationValues are actually the ones I want to query.

Comment: I don't want to delete rows from the db. The translationValues are actually the ones I want to query. Every translationValue object in the set contains the value for a specific language. I want to ask "give me only the english translation for this key", upon which I would get back a Translation object with a translationValue set size of 1 -> only the translationValue who's language variable contains "en". But I also want to be able to be like "give me all the translations for this key", which would give me back the same Translation object but with a much larger set of TranslationValue objects.

Comment: If you want to select only one TranslationValue, then select that. If you select a Translation, it will always contain all its tranlation values.